# Odata No NavigationLink factory was found

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, odata

I am currently working on a mvc4 web api odata service where I want to return a List of Users where Users have a list of Languages. When I want to get the Users I get the following error:

**Error:**

```
<m:innererror>
<m:message>
The 'ObjectContent`1' type failed to serialize the response body for content type 'application/json; charset=utf-8'.
</m:message>
<m:type>System.InvalidOperationException</m:type>
<m:stacktrace/>
<m:internalexception>
<m:message>
No NavigationLink factory was found for the navigation property 'Languages' from entity type 'MvcWebRole1.Models.User' on entity set 'Users'. Try calling HasNavigationPropertyLink on the EntitySetConfiguration.
 Parameter name: navigationProperty
</m:message>
<m:type>System.ArgumentException</m:type>
<m:stacktrace>
at System.Web.Http.OData.Builder.EntitySetLinkBuilderAnnotation.BuildNavigationLink(EntityInstanceContext instanceContext, IEdmNavigationProperty navigationProperty, ODataMetadataLevel metadataLevel)
 at System.Web.Http.OData.Formatter.Serialization.ODataEntityTypeSerializer.WriteNavigationLinks(EntityInstanceContext context, ODataWriter writer, ODataSerializerContext writeContext)
 at System.Web.Http.OData.Formatter.Serialization.ODataEntityTypeSerializer.WriteEntry(Object graph, IEnumerable`1 propertyBag, ODataWriter writer, ODataSerializerContext writeContext)
 at System.Web.Http.OData.Formatter.Serialization.ODataEntityTypeSerializer.WriteObjectInline(Object graph, ODataWriter writer, ODataSerializerContext writeContext)
 at System.Web.Http.OData.Formatter.Serialization.ODataFeedSerializer.WriteFeed(Object graph, ODataWriter writer, ODataSerializerContext writeContext)
 at System.Web.Http.OData.Formatter.Serialization.ODataFeedSerializer.WriteObjectInline(Object graph, ODataWriter writer, ODataSerializerContext writeContext)
 at System.Web.Http.OData.Formatter.Serialization.ODataFeedSerializer.WriteObject(Object graph, ODataMessageWriter messageWriter, ODataSerializerContext writeContext)
 at System.Web.Http.OData.Formatter.ODataMediaTypeFormatter.<>c__DisplayClassa.<WriteToStreamAsync>b__9()
 at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskHelpers.RunSynchronously(Action action, CancellationToken token)
</m:stacktrace>
</m:internalexception>
</m:innererror>
```

**My User looks like this:**

```
public class User
{
    [Key]
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    public string Password { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Language> Languages { get; set; }

    public User()
    {
        Languages = new List<Language>();
    }
}
```

**and my UsersController for OData looks like this:**

```
public class UsersController : EntitySetController<User, int>
{
    WorldChatContext db = new WorldChatContext();

    public override IQueryable<User> Get()
    {
        return db.Users.AsQueryable();
    }

    protected override User GetEntityByKey(int key)
    {
        return db.Users.FirstOrDefault(p => p.UserId == key);
    }

    public override HttpResponseMessage Post(User entity)
    {
        db.Users.Add(entity);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return base.Post(entity);
    }
}
```

I am calling the following url which i setup in my routing: `http://127.0.0.1:81/odata/Users` it works if I comment navigation property in my User model.

What am i doing wrong? I already tryed to put [Serializable, KnownType(typeof(Language))] on top of my user class but for some reason i cant use KnownType. How can i make my OData work with this navigation property?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You are missing the entity set for Language. A navigation property points to an entity and has to be bound to an entity set. In your model builder code, add this line to fix the issue.

```
builder.EntitySet<Language>("languages");
```

What this does is to create the entity set 'languages'. The convention model builder binds a navigation property to an entity set if there is one. So, the navigation property `Languages` on the entity type `User` will be bound to the entity set `languages`.

Comment: thanks that actually did the job and it didnt gave the error anymore! It doesnt return the languages in the odata result though, do you know why that is? I have been reading about the expand query but it doesnt seem to work.

Comment: OData doesn't expand the relationships by default. They are represented instead as links. To get the related languages as well while querying for Users, you need to use the uri `http://localhost/odata/Users?$expand=Languages`. Check out the documentation at http://www.odata.org/documentation/odata-v3-documentation/url-conventions/#513_Expand_System_Query_Option

Comment: What if we don't want to offer an entity set for languages to simplify our API, is there an example using HasNavigationPropertyLink?

Comment: OData V3 doesn't let you do that. `languages` has to be exposed as a root level entity set. However, you are free to just return a `404` when someone accesses that entityset.

Comment: How do you return a 404 when someone access an entity set. Specifically when they access it as a $expand property